# Auto Scaling Image Annotation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Scalize is a jQuery plugin used for adding custom markers (hotspots) with custom popovers and animations to containers or images.

But now When I click one by one on pointer it show all one by one But I am trying to show only one so when click another pointer will close the other which already opened.

Here is my [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/u8dcn7ze/)

```
    (function(jQuery) {
    "use strict";

    //----------------------------------------//
    // Variable
    //----------------------------------------//
    var variable = {
        width : 0,
        height : 0,
        selector : '.item-point',
        styleSelector : 'circle',
        animationSelector : 'pulse2',
        animationPopoverIn : 'flipInY',
        animationPopoverOut : 'flipOutY', 
        onInit : null,
        getSelectorElement : null,
        getValueRemove : null
    }

    //----------------------------------------//
    // Scaling
    //----------------------------------------//
    var scaling = {
        settings : null,
        //----------------------------------------//
        // Initialize
        //----------------------------------------//
        init: function(el, options){
            this.settings = jQuery.extend(variable, options);
            this.event(el);            

            scaling.layout(el);
            jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
                scaling.layout(el);
            });
            jQuery(el).find('.target').on('load', function(){
                scaling.layout(el);
            });
            jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){
                scaling.layout(el);
            });
        },

        //----------------------------------------//
        // Event
        //----------------------------------------//
        event : function(elem){
            // Set Style Selector
            if ( this.settings.styleSelector ) {
                jQuery(this.settings.selector).addClass( this.settings.styleSelector );
            }

            // Set Animation
            if ( this.settings.animationSelector ) {
                if( this.settings.animationSelector == 'marker' ){
                    jQuery(this.settings.selector).addClass( this.settings.animationSelector );
                    jQuery(this.settings.selector).append('<div class="pin"></div>')
                    jQuery(this.settings.selector).append('<div class="pulse"></div>')
                }else{
                    jQuery(this.settings.selector).addClass( this.settings.animationSelector );
                }
            }

            // Event On Initialize
            if ( jQuery.isFunction( this.settings.onInit ) ) {
                this.settings.onInit();
            }

            // Content add class animated element
            jQuery(elem).find('.content').addClass('animated');

            // Wrapper selector
            jQuery(this.settings.selector).wrapAll( "<div class='wrap-selector' />");

            // Event Selector
            jQuery(this.settings.selector).each(function(){

                // Toggle
                jQuery('.toggle', this).on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    jQuery(this).closest(scaling.settings.selector).toggleClass('active');

                    // Selector Click
                    var content = jQuery(this).closest(scaling.settings.selector).data('popover'),
                        id = jQuery(content);

                    if(jQuery(this).closest(scaling.settings.selector).hasClass('active') && !jQuery(this).closest(scaling.settings.selector).hasClass('disabled')){
                        if ( jQuery.isFunction( scaling.settings.getSelectorElement ) ) {
                            scaling.settings.getSelectorElement(jQuery(this).closest(scaling.settings.selector));
                        }
                        id.fadeIn(500,function(){

                            if( getBrowserName() == "Safari" ){
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    id.removeClass('flipInY');
                                },125);

                            }
                        });
                        scaling.layout(elem);
                        id.removeClass(scaling.settings.animationPopoverOut);
                        id.addClass(scaling.settings.animationPopoverIn);
                    }else{
                        if(jQuery.isFunction( scaling.settings.getValueRemove )){
                            scaling.settings.getValueRemove(jQuery(this).closest(scaling.settings.selector));
                        }
                        id.removeClass(scaling.settings.animationPopoverIn);
                        id.addClass(scaling.settings.animationPopoverOut);
                        id.delay(500).fadeOut();
                    }
                });

                // Exit
                var target = jQuery(this).data('popover'),
                    idTarget = jQuery(target);
                idTarget.find('.exit').on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // selector.removeClass('active');
                    jQuery('[data-popover="'+ target +'"]').removeClass('active');
                    idTarget.removeClass(scaling.settings.animationPopoverIn);
                    idTarget.addClass(scaling.settings.animationPopoverOut);
                    idTarget.delay(500).fadeOut();
                });
            });
        },

        //----------------------------------------//
        // Layout
        //----------------------------------------//
        layout : function(elem){

            // Get Original Image
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = elem.find('.target').attr("src");

            // Variable
            var width = image.naturalWidth,
                height = image.naturalHeight,
                getWidthLess = jQuery(elem).width(),
                setPersenWidth = getWidthLess/width * 100,
                setHeight = height * setPersenWidth / 100;

            // Set Heigh Element
            jQuery(elem).css("height", setHeight);

            // Resize Width
            if( jQuery(window).width() < width ){
                jQuery(elem).stop().css("width","100%");
            }else{
                jQuery(elem).stop().css("width",width);
            }

            // Set Position Selector
            jQuery(this.settings.selector).each(function(){
                if( jQuery(window).width() < width ){
                    var getTop = jQuery(this).data("top") * setPersenWidth / 100,
                        getLeft = jQuery(this).data("left") * setPersenWidth / 100;
                }else{
                    var getTop = jQuery(this).data("top"),
                        getLeft = jQuery(this).data("left");
                }
                jQuery(this).css("top", getTop + "px");
                jQuery(this).css("left", getLeft + "px");

                // Target Position
                var target = jQuery(this).data('popover'),
                    allSize = jQuery(target).find('.head').outerHeight() + jQuery(target).find('.body').outerHeight() + jQuery(target).find('.footer').outerHeight();
                jQuery(target).css("left", getLeft + "px");
                jQuery(target).css("height", allSize + "px");

                if(jQuery(target).hasClass('bottom')){
                    var getHeight = jQuery(target).outerHeight(),
                        getTopBottom = getTop - getHeight;
                    jQuery(target).css("top", getTopBottom + "px");
                }else if(jQuery(target).hasClass('center')){
                    var getHeight = jQuery(target).outerHeight() * 0.50,
                        getTopBottom = getTop - getHeight;
                    jQuery(target).css("top", getTopBottom + "px");
                }else{
                    jQuery(target).css("top", getTop + "px");
                }

                jQuery('.toggle', this).css('width', jQuery(this).outerWidth());
                jQuery('.toggle', this).css('height', jQuery(this).outerHeight());

                // Toggle Size
                if(jQuery(this).find('.pin')){
                    var widthThis = jQuery('.pin', this).outerWidth(),
                        heightThis = jQuery('.pin', this).outerHeight();
                    jQuery('.toggle', this).css('width', widthThis);
                    jQuery('.toggle', this).css('height', heightThis);                    
                }
            });
        }

    };

    //----------------------------------------//
    // Scalize Plugin
    //----------------------------------------//
    jQuery.fn.scalize = function(options){
        return scaling.init(this, options);
    };

}(jQuery));

function getBrowserName() {
    var name = "Unknown";
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1){
        name = "MSIE";
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")!=-1){
        name = "Firefox";
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera")!=-1){
        name = "Opera";
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1){
        name = "Chrome";
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari")!=-1){
        name = "Safari";
    }
    return name;   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your initialisation:

```
        getSelectorElement: function(el) {
          $('.item-point.active').not($(el)[0]).find('.toggle').click();
        }
```

This hooks into the getSelectorElement method in the Scalize plugin and triggers a click on any active (open) elements that don't match the most recently clicked item.

Add it like so:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.scalize').scalize({
            styleSelector: 'circle',
            animationPopoverIn: 'fadeIn',
            animationPopoverOut: 'fadeOut',
            animationSelector: 'pulse2',
            getSelectorElement: function(el) {
              $('.item-point.active').not($(el)[0]).find('.toggle').click();
            }
        });         
    });
```

Note, because this is hooking into existing methods in the plugin it's a little safer (no unpredictable side effects, plus you get the intended transition out on the disappearing elements). [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eh0afquv/).

Comment: A lot cleaner than what I wrote. Did not realize `getSelectorElement` was what I was looking for when I was skimming the very brief docs.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the most intuitive method name :)

Comment: @delinear Your code is nicely works but not on wordpress. How can I make it wordpress compatible

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjaf5L1y/) to work.

TL;DR: Anytime an point is clicked, if there are other active siblings, loop over them and hide their popups.

It isn't a pretty way of doing it but it is working in the Fiddle.

```js
$('.scalize').on('click', '.item-point', (function() {
  $(this).siblings('.item-point.active').each(function() {
    var popover = $(this).data('popover');
    $(popover).removeClass('fadeIn').css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I am adding to my main site.